# How to set attachment compulsory for Imagebutton in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a field as `Image`. I want to set it compulsory on `button` click event in javascript.

Hereis my html

```
<input type="image" name="ImgAttach" id="ImgAttach" src="../Images/attachment_1.png" onclick="return Imgclick();" />
```

and button code

```
<input type="submit" name="CmdSave" value="Save" onclick="return FunSaveValidate();" id="CmdSave" class="button" />
```

**Note** I want it in javascript.

For more info see [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8b9hm4ma/)

Comment: What do you mean by "set it compulsory"? The `<input type="image">` element must exist?

Comment: @shaochuancs: I mean it should be a **required field** on button click

Comment: Why do you want it to be a required field? `<input type="image">` is used to submit form, not to select local image file.

Comment: @shaochuancs: I want it as a required field, can we do with this or not ?

Comment: hmmm, what do you want to achieve by making it as "required field"? Can you explain with some detail?

Comment: @shaochuancs: See, I have a form. In which there are many fields including `image` field too. So I want to put a validation that user cannot submit the form without attachment. Does it clear now ?

Comment: Ah, I understand, please see my answer.

Comment: is your question correctly answered? If yes, maybe you can "accept" one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="image">` is used to submit form (similar with `<input type="submit">`), not to attach image files (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#image-button-state-(type=image))

In order to attach image files and make it as **required field**, please use `<input type="file" accept="image/*" required>`

Comment: can u update with code in the fiddle and send me the link ?

Comment: Hi, stack, @Venkatesan S has attached a fiddle link in his/her answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<input type="file" accept="image/*" required>` instead of `<input type="image">` in your form.

`<input type="image">` will submit the form

See [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhxgyxbm/)